# How to create Right Click Menu in jtable

Tags: java, swing, drop-down-menu, menu, jtable

I want create a drop down menu when the user right-clicks on a row in jtable..can anyone suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done exactly the same way as other `JPopupMenu`. You add a `MouseListener` to the `JTable` and upon a right-click, you show the `JPopupMenu`.

Check out the [Menus tutorial of Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup)

As mentionned by @kleopatra, you can also directly set a `JPopupMenu` on any `JComponent` (or its descendendants, using `setInheritsPopupMenu()`), with [`setComponentPopupMenu()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu%28javax.swing.JPopupMenu%29) which will take care for you of showing the associated `JPopupMenu`, when appropriate (ie, a right-click on most platform)

Comment: you might consider mentioning that the tutorial is outdated - except _maybe_ when needing popup content that depends on the location of the mouse event :-)

Comment: @kleopatra in what way is it outdated? Is there a new way to build and display `JPopupMenu`'s?

Comment: yeah, there is: setComponentPopupMenu